# Is it possible to import two jars with same packages?

Tags: java, java-9, java-module, java-11

I'm migrating project from Java 8 to Java 11, and modularity introduced in java 9 is giving me a headache. 
Couple jars have same packages, but different classes. This is giving me error

```
module SomeModule reads package my.package from both ModuleA and ModuleB
```

I wonder how to deal with cases like that, given that not all jars are under my control, refactoring is not a solution.

Answer (score 1):

One of the way is to make sure both these jars end up on the **`classpath`** in **[The Unnamed Module](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/spec/sotms/#the-unnamed-module)**. But do take a note that

> The *unnamed module exports all of its packages*. This enables flexible
>   migration...
>   It does not, however, mean that code in a *named module* can access
>   types in the *unnamed module*.
>
> A *named module* cannot, in fact, even
>   declare a dependence upon the *unnamed module*. This restriction is
>   intentional, since allowing named modules to depend upon the arbitrary
>   content of the class path would make *reliable configuration*
>   impossible.

Ofcourse the ideal solution would be to do a bottom up migration and ensure that no two modules expose the same package to the module that `requires` both of them.

Comment: .. *given that not all jars are under my control, refactoring is not a solution* ..

Comment: And how, pray, does one accomplish "One of the way is to make sure both these jars end up on the classpath in The Unnamed Module."? If I have the interface class in one jar and one of its implementations in another jar and I put them on the classpath: BOOM! Not allowed! Without even using Jigsaw, just wanting to compile